# What will be the exact color if I am getting value 1 in "Separation" colorspace using itext7 pdf extraction?

Tags: itext7, color-space, pdf-extraction

I have been extracting pdf with itext7 and using textrenderinfo.getfillcolor() for fill color of text. I am getting colorspace as "Separation" colorspace and colorvalue as 1. How can I get this colorspace in rgb ?

Comment: Please add your code and the PDF to the question

Comment: @Shivanand *A Separation colour space provides a means for specifying the use of additional colorants or for isolating the control of individual colour components of a device colour space for a subtractive device.* (ISO 32000-1) Thus, while such a separation color space does include a transform to a more normal color space, it often makes sense to treat it as something special. That being said, to show how to proceed by example we'd need a PDF and a pointer to the text in question in it.